# Xamarin.iOS Error on Build MessagingRemoteException, DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I encountered this error upon building the app. I could not build successfully. (Xamarin on Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, Xamarin Mac Agent is already connected)

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(1025,3): error : MessagingRemoteException: An error occured on client Build42211 while executing a reply for topic xvs/Build/4.2.2.11/execute-task/CompanyName.iOS/83ecc20%2FACTool

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(1025,3): error : DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/Users/glennrodriguez/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/CompanyName.iOS/83ecc20ddd53d18137bcee59a20ad010/Resources/Images.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset/Contents.json".

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this issue before and it usually is resolved by cleaning the project and clearing the build cache on the Mac.

The build server cache is located on the Mac build host in the folder:
`~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs`
Note that the `~/Library` folder is hidden by default in Finder, so if need be use Finder's Go->Go to Folder menu and enter `~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs` to open the folder. You can safely delete the sub-folders of the above folder to clear the build cache on the build host.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what jgoldberger is saying, you can try the following found at this link: https://xamarin.github.io/bugzilla-archives/45/45083/bug.html comments 8 and 9 were very helpful.

For me, the solution I am working on had been Merged or Branched in TFS. When this occurs it creates an ItemGroup for the AppIcons in your Media.xcassets. This propagates the erros you are seeing. In the past I have used jgoldberger's solution and it worked fine for me. But just yesterday deleting the builds folder on the build machine did not work. The following steps helped get me up and running again.

Right-click on your iOS project and unload your iOS project.
Right-click and edit your iOS project.
Find the ItemGroup below and remove the entire ItemGroup.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ImageAsset Include="Media.xcassets\AppIcons.appiconset\AppIcon.png">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
    <ImageAsset Include="Media.xcassets\AppIcons.appiconset\Contents.json">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
    <ImageAsset Include="Media.xcassets\AppIcons.appiconset\mylogoicon.png">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
    <ImageAsset Include="Media\AppIcons.appiconset\Contents.json">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
    <ImageAsset Include="Media\LaunchImages\Contents.json">
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </ImageAsset>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Perform a clean solution, remove the builds as jgoldberger suggest in your ~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs , and rebuild after that.