# Could not load the framework 'IBFoundation'

Tags: xamarin.forms, xcode13

I am using XCode 13 Beta 3 build 13A5192j on macOS Monterey (Version 12.0 Beta 21A5284e)  with Visual Studio 2020 Preview.

When ever I am trying to run the Xamarin-Form application on real device, I am getting below error, but I am able to create archive :

> Could not load the framework 'IBFoundation' (path: /Applications/XCode-beta.app/Contents/Frameworks/IBFoundation.framework/IBFoundation): not found.

I tried with visual studio 2019 (stable Version) and Xcode 12.* (stable version) but getting some connectivity error

Comment: Xamarin may not support XCode13 yet,  try to downgrade Xcode and Visual studio to stable version(`Xcode :12.5 , Visual studio : 2019`). And also try to switch `Linker Behavior` to `Don't Link`.

Comment: Thanks @ColeX-MSFT . I have removed the beta version of the XCode and using the current stable version 12.5.1 with Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 (Version 16.10.3) Xamarin version 16.10.000.234 (d16-10@ecaf29b), Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   14.20.0.24 (c4b89cddb) but getting below error : MessagingRemoteException: An error occurred on client Build1610000234 while executing a reply for topic xvs/build/execute-task/<ProjectName>.iOS/c843981002fDetectSdkLocations
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1 <ProjectName?.iOS

Comment: Try clean and rebuild ,refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026935/xamarin-ios-error-on-build-messagingremoteexception-directorynotfoundexception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was issue with the Beta version of both softwares.
I was using Beta version of MacOs (Monterey beta 4), Beta Version of XCode (XCode 13) and Preview Version of Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11 Insider Preview.

When I removed the XCode 13 with xCode 12 then also it was showing same error. It worked when I removed Visual Studio 2022 Preview also.

So everything fine now with Windows 11 Insider Preview, Visaul Studio 2017 (Latest), XCode 12.5.1 and MacOs Monterey Beta.

Hope it will help someone if facing same issue as I was facing.

Answer (score 8):

Xamarin is working on an update: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/12778

They give 3 possible workarounds:

> - You can download Xcode 12.5 from the downloads page in the Apple Developer Portal and continue to use it.
> - If you need to keep Xcode 13 but want to use our current stable d16-10 bits you will need to install the following in you macOS machine
>   xamarin.ios-14.20.0.27.pkg
>   xamarin.mac-7.14.0.27.pkg
> - Use a build from our xcode13-ios branch, this is where our next stable release is coming out and it includes all the iOS 15 SDKs APIs, that said we are still ironing it out.
>   xamarin.ios-15.0.0.0.pkg